# STM32F4 : Why my program freezes when I use USART (GPS) and uSD (FatFs) at the same time?

Tags: gps, freeze, sd-card, stm32f4

### Long story short

I am working on a STM32F469 based project where I would like, among others things, to save GPS data (from an Adafruit Ultimate GPS Breakout V3) into an uSD Card (controlled via SPI interface with FatFs layer). I am using essentially HAL library to initialize and control peripherals. The program uses a lot of peripherals and so far everything was working fine (RTC, I2C, UART, SPI, LTCD, DSI, RAM, etc...).

I am struggling with the uSD Card to save GPS Data : my program freeze when I decide to stop to process GPS data and close my file.

Before we go any further :

- I was already using, into this same project, the SD Card to save and retrieve various data from and to an .csv file (other part of the program) : it was and still works perfectly fine when I am doing this. As I said before, the uSD is controlled via SPI interface and FatFs ;
- The GPS communication is done via USART6 peripheral with interrupt management (IRQ at every byte received). If I don't use the uSD part with GPS, I am receiving GPS Data, can dislay them on my screen and stop the reception. If I use the uSD part with GPS, I am receiving GPS Data, can display them on my screen as long as I don't stop the reception. When I stop the reception (and decide afterward to close the file), the program freeze (or wait something).

### The functions

```
// The program goes into this part of the program when I push a button

// GPS enabled

// HMI display
DGT_DisplayStringLCD(RECO_GPS_VALX, RECO_GPS_VALY, (uint8_t *)"ENABLED", CENTER);

// USART6 initialization with IRQ
GPIO_InitTypeDef  GPIO_InitStruct;

__HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();
__HAL_RCC_USART6_CLK_ENABLE();

GPIO_InitStruct.Pin       = USART_TX_PIN;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode      = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull      = GPIO_PULLUP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed     = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF8_USART6;

HAL_GPIO_Init(USART_TX_BASE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

GPIO_InitStruct.Pin         = USART_RX_PIN;
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate   = GPIO_AF8_USART6;

HAL_GPIO_Init(USART_RX_BASE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

huart->Instance             = USART6;

huart->Init.BaudRate        = 9600;
huart->Init.WordLength      = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
huart->Init.StopBits        = UART_STOPBITS_1;
huart->Init.Parity          = UART_PARITY_NONE;
huart->Init.Mode            = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
huart->Init.HwFlowCtl       = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;

if(HAL_UART_Init(&uart6Handle) != HAL_OK){
    return HAL_ERROR;
}

__HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(huart, UART_IT_ERR);
__HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(huart, UART_IT_RXNE);

HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART6_IRQn, 2, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART6_IRQn);


// IRQ when 1 byte is received
HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&uart6Handle, (uint8_t*)USART6_RXBuffer, 1);

// GPS configuration
GPS_Config();

// uSD configuration
if(FATFS_LinkDriver(&SD_Driver, SDPath) == 0){
    if(BSP_SD_Init() != MSD_OK){
        FATFS_UnLinkDriver(SDPath);
        err = HAL_ERROR;
    }else{
        if(f_mount(&SDFatFs, (TCHAR const*)SDPath, 0) != FR_OK){
            FATFS_UnLinkDriver(SDPath);
            err = HAL_ERROR;
        }else{
            sprintf(csvPath, "gpsrec%u.txt", 1);
            err = f_open(&MyCSVFile, (TCHAR const*)csvPath, FA_WRITE | FA_READ | FA_CREATE_ALWAYS);
            GPS_RecordInit(&MyCSVFile); // Write header
        }
    }
}else{ // FatFs_LinkDriver error
    FATFS_UnLinkDriver(SDPath);
    err = HAL_ERROR;
}
```

Into this part of the program, when I decide to "enable" the GPS, I initialize the USART6 peripheral and its interrupts (ERR & RXNE). When it's done, I call the *HAL_UART_Receive_IT* function for 1 byte. Doing this way an interrupt arises at every character received from the GPS which is processed into the callback function (see below). The function GPS_Config() is used to configure the GPS card (RMC only, baudrate). Finally I configure the uSD card with FatFs function. It is done the same way I am doing it in other part of the program where it works fine. When I configure the uSD card, I open a file and write a header into it.

```
// GPS is disabled

// HMI Display
DGT_DisplayStringLCD(RECO_GPS_VALX, RECO_GPS_VALY, (uint8_t *)"DISABLED", CENTER);

// IRQ disabled
HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(USART6_IRQn);

// Clear the buffer (useless ?)
HAL_UART_Receive(&uart6Handle, dummyBuffer, 9, 100);

// Reset USART6 peripheral
HAL_UART_DeInit(&uart6Handle);
__HAL_UART_DISABLE_IT(&uart6Handle, UART_IT_ERR);
__HAL_UART_DISABLE_IT(&uart6Handle, UART_IT_RXNE);
uart6Handle.RxState = HAL_UART_STATE_READY;

// Write the footer
GPS_RecordEnd(&MyCSVFile);

// Close the file
f_close(&MyCSVFile);

// Unlink the driver
FATFS_UnLinkDriver(SDPath);
```

This part of the program is what is done when I decide to "disable" the GPS. I disable the USART6 interrupt. The following *HAL_UART_Receive* function is used to clear the buffer. I reset the USART6 peripheral. Finally I am writing a footer into my file, close the file and unlink the driver.
This part of the program has been through a lot of modifications since this is where my program freezes. I have switched uSD / GPS order call functions without any success. It is not robust anymore but I am just trying to close my file for the moment and be able to read what I wrote.

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart){

    if(huart->Instance == USART6){

        if(RMCProcessing == 0){
            // Only process char received if a RMC 
            // frame is not already in process

            if(USART6_RXBuffer[0] == '$'){
                // char received id the beginning of the RMC frame

                RMCReception = 1;   // Frame receiving
                RMCProcessing = 0;  // Prevent the GPSProcess function to process the current frame until it is received

                // Save the first char received
                RX_GPSBuffer[inc] = USART6_RXBuffer[0];
                inc++;

            }else{
                // The char received is in the middle of the frame

                if(RMCReception){
                    // It is part of the current detected RMC frame (middle or end ?)

                    if(USART6_RXBuffer[0] == '\n'){
                        // End of the frame detected

                        RX_GPSBuffer[inc] = USART6_RXBuffer[0];
                        inc = 0;    // Reset the buffer
                        RMCReception = 0; // Frame completely received
                        RMCProcessing = 1; // The frame can be process by GPSProcess()

                    }else{
                        // Middle

                        RX_GPSBuffer[inc] = USART6_RXBuffer[0];
                        inc++;

                        if(inc >= 250){
                            // To prevent unexpected error

                            inc = 0; 
                            RMCReception = 0; 
                            RMCProcessing = 0;

                        }

                    }

                }else{
                    // Char is ignored
                    // Reset the buffer and process state

                    inc = 0; // Reset the buffer
                    RMCReception = 0;
                    RMCProcessing = 0;

                }


        }


        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&uart6Handle, (uint8_t*)USART6_RXBuffer, 1);


}
```

This is the callback function for the USART6 peripheral (when I receive a byte). Nothing particular I guess. It serves just to detect and save into a buffer a RMC frame from the GPS.
The received RMC framed is then process into a function placed into a while loop (not relevant here but I can add it if asked).

Just a reminder :

- Into these functions, I don't even write GPS data into the uSD card (I only write the header and footer). The part where I save the GPS data into the uSD card is coded but commented for now. Since I have the problem without any saving, I don't think it is relevant ;
- If I only comment the uSD part written into this functions, I can enabled, received and display all the GPS data. I can disable the GPS. No issue, my program is still running normally ;
- If I only comment the USART6 part, I can mount, open, write and close the file as many times as I want. When I unplug the uSD card and read its content on a PC, I have my file and its content (header and footer) ;
- If I use the functions as they are displayed here (cleaned yet), I can received GPS Data, no error (apparently) when I mount and write into my file but when I stop the GPS (and decide to close my file). The program freeze (or hangs I don't know).

### The clue

I suspect the USART6 IRQ management to be the problem but I don't really know in what manner. Let me explain : A couple of times the GPS didn't initialize well (or the GPS didn't receive any data from sattelites ?). No GPS data was displayed even if I have enabled it. At this moment, I was able to disabled it without any freeze. I think the freeze occurs when the RX buffer is not empty (or when the IRQ is not raised, I don't really know).

Anyway, do you have any idea why I have this behaviour ?

Thanks !